# Can't get token outside of function in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project using nodejs, mongodb (mongoose), and graphql in the backend. Currently, I'm trying to make my log-in process more secure, but I'm running into an issue. I can't get the user's token outside of the function.

```
login: async (_, { email, password }) => {
   try {
     var token;
      User.getAuthenticated(email, password, function(err, user, reason) {
      var token;
      if (err) throw err;

      if (user) {
           // handle login success
           console.log('login success');
           token = user.createToken();
           //return token;
      }
  
     
           console.log('token', token)
           return token
      })
      console.log('token?', token)
      
      return {
        token,
      };
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  },
```

I tried using then() after the function:

```
User.getAuthenticated(email, password, async function(err, user, reason) {

...

}).then((result) => console.log('result', result))
```

but I keep getting `result undefined`.

In my User.js document, `getAuthenticated()` looks like:

```
UserSchema.statics.getAuthenticated = async function(email, password, cb) { 
    this.findOne({email}, function(err, user) { 
      user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
          if (err) return cb(err);

          if (isMatch) {
              if (!user.loginAttempts && !user.lockUntil) return cb(null, user);
              var updates = {
                  $set: { loginAttempts: 0 },
                  $unset: { lockUntil: 1 }
              };
              return user.updateOne(updates, function(err) {
                  if (err) return cb(err);
                  return cb(null, user);
              });
          }
    })
  })
};
```

Where `comparePassword()` looks like:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        return cb(null, isMatch);
    })
};
```

I would really appreciate any help or advice on how I can get this variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved as follow:

```js
const token = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      User.getAuthenticated(email, password, (err, user, reason) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }

        if (user) {
          console.log('login success');
          resolve(user.createToken());
        } else {
          reject(new Error('Login failed'));
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy for days. I had tried just     ```const token = await User.getAuthenticated(email, password, (err, user, reason)...``` and it hadn't worked so I figured that wasn't going to work, but it makes a lot of sense that the missing component was the promise.